# Sort products by drop-down attribute on category page

Tags: dropdown-attribute, resource-model

I created an attribute which Input Type is drop-down and has custom source model, similar with brand. Now if I sort the product list by this attribute products are sorted by option id rather than option label. How do I should configure the attribute (or it's source model) to sort products by label. 
Thanks